# AVAudioPlayer play multiple times same sound without interrupting

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a scrollview. And I want to play a sound everytime I reach 1/7 of it. When the user scrolls slowly it works because the sound is finished before the other one gets fired.

But if its too fast : i have 2 options :

- Ignore the following sound that should fire
- Stop the previous one and play the following

But what I want is to have the first one finishing playing even if the second (or even the 3rd, 4th etc.) has started playing.

Can I do this with one AVAudioplayer ?

```
var alertSound = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Transit", withExtension: "aif")
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)

var error:NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

Comment: You'll need multiple players to achieve this. If it's a UI sound effect might be better linking AudioToolbox framework and use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound function. This should achieve the behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a quick example to show me. So that I could mark your answer as accepted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you'll need multiple **AVAudioPlayers**, one player won't do the job. However the **AudioToolbox** framework probably will cater for your requirements.

You basically create a system sound ID for your sound and fire it off whenever you want. Once it's fired the sound will play out, the down side is no control over volume but that shouldn't matter in this case.

basic example would be (obj-C sorry)

```
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"soundName" ofType:@"aif"];

    SystemSoundID soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)([NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]), &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```